# Mac OSX 10.8: Items In /Library/Startupitems won't run or execute

Tags: mac, osx-mountain-lion

I'm trying to run [Feross' SpoofMAC](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC/) on every startup but it not work. I have followed every instructions and have made sure of that because been doing this for like 5 hours. 
I even tried Googling for answers, some showed method of using LoginHook and rc.common which I have no idea about.
I added the required files in the below folder on Mac

```
/Library/StartupItems/SpoofMAC
```

Even permissions are correctly set according to the ReadMe provided on the website.
I have tried finding a solution for the past 5 hours but can't find a way. 
It seems items in /Library/StartupItems won't run or execute. I did not see any Terminal window flash during startup.
Do help with this issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a LaunchAgent to have a specific task run on login.
See an example [there](http://www.patrickpatoray.com/index.php?Page=69)

Comment: Does this work if I want to run it as root?